# Date Fields Calculating

Tags: formula

I have a scenario where I should get the number of days between task Due Date and completed Date. Ex : Due date is : 24th March 2022 Completed Date is : 30th March 2022

In between the number of working days I am able to get the result as 4 Days,

But if  my completed Date is on 20th March I should get the values in negative values (Ex: -4)

Can any one help me how to have the Formulae For my requirement.

Comment: What have you tried? You can [edit] your question with your attempt at doing this.

Answer (score 2):

[SalesForce Help Docs here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5) note the following in the 'Find the Number of Weekdays Between Two Dates' section:

> Calculating how many weekdays passed between two dates is slightly
> more complex than calculating total elapsed days. In this example,
> weekdays are Monday through Friday. The basic strategy is to choose a
> reference Monday from the past and find out how many full weeks and
> any additional portion of a week have passed between the reference
> date and your date. These values are multiplied by five for a five-day
> work week, and then the difference between them is taken to calculate
> weekdays.

```
(5 * ( FLOOR( ( date_1 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( date_1 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
-
(5 * ( FLOOR( ( date_2 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( date_2 - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
```

> In this formula, date_1 is the more recent date and date_2 is the
> earlier date. If your work week runs shorter or longer than five days,
> replace all fives in the formula with the length of your week.

This formula should result in a negative number if Date 2 is more recent than Date 1.

To test this, I built a report using a row-level formula column. I set the field result to 'number' and entered the formula from above, replacing date_1 with Shipping Date and date_2 with Install Date.  This would cause the formula to subtract the Install Date (think of this as the higher number) from the Shipping Date (think of this as the lower number).

Since the install date will always be later than the shipping date, we should expect the formula result to show a negative number - Which, as you can see, was the case here.

[image]

As long as you don't have your formula wrapped in ABS(), you should see negative numbers when date_2 is later (more recent) than date_1.